# Check to see if a certain cell has been selected in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net

I have a dataGridView. I will post a picture of it.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fgtlXyD.png]

I am wanting to know how I could execute code on selection of each member name.

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: already spent 2 days trying to figure this out even with google. please just help.

Comment: i am within my asking rights. if your not going to help then why are you even here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CellClik event and check if the column index is the desired column. For example:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value)
    End If
End Sub
```